# How do I replace a variable with a - symbol

Tags: python, list, variables, replace

I am trying to make a hangman project and to do so, I need to be able to replace the `word_chosen` variable with `-`. Does anyone know how? Let me put in my code:

```
import random

import time

word_list = ['that', 'poop', 'situation', 'coding', 'python']

word_chosen = random.choice(word_list)

your_name = input("What is your name?")

time.sleep(1)

print("Hello " + your_name + ", lets play some hangman!")
```

Comment: To clarify you want to replace word_chosen string (e.g. 'python') with the string '-'? No where in your program do I see you using the `word_chosen` variable to show the user a string, be it the dash or any of your `word_list` strings. You will need to provide more information on what you want to do with it.

Comment: @LaBeaux I believe they mean they want  to replace *characters* in the word with `-`.

Comment: You might want something like this: `word_chosen_hidden = '-' * len(word_chosen)`

Comment: I'm guessing this is for a school project? Without completely telling you how to replace each character with a dash, and unveil it upon each guess, start with @costaparas recommendation above. Then think about how to iterate through the characters in the string to see if it matches the users guess. If it matches, update your `word_chose_hidden` with the correct letter from that index.

Comment: um lol, actually its my own project, I am learning python myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to replace the word with `-` according to how many letters the word has, so just add this at the end of the code you have already:

```
hidden_word = ""

for i in word_chosen:
    hidden_word += "-"

print (hidden_word)
```

This loops through selected word and adds a dash for every letter in it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe @costaparas has the right idea:

```py
import random

import time

word_list = ['that', 'poop', 'situation', 'coding', 'python']

word_chosen = random.choice(word_list)

hidden_word_chosen = '-' * len(word_chosen)

print(hidden_word_chosen)
```

Output:

```sh
------
```

Answer (score 1):

Start simple and work your way up. Think about what actions you need to perform. These are your program requirements. We need to:

1. Show a word with the current characters hidden, using a list of already guessed characters.
2. Ask the user for letter and add it to the list of guessed characters.
3. If that character was already chosen, go back to step 2.
4. If the character is in the word, increase their incorrect guess count.
5. If all the characters are found, tell the user they have won, then exit.
6. If the user has made too many incorrect guess, tell the user they have lost, then exit.
7. Otherwise, go back to step 1.

To help get you started, lets see how you would write a method to perform action 1.

```
def print_hidden_word(word_chosen, characters_guessed):
    result = ""
    for character in word_chosen:
        if character in characters_guessed:
            result += character
        else:
            result += "-"
    print("Your word is: " + result)
```

We can test this function separately to try it out:

```
>>> print(print_hidden_word("python", ["p", "t", "n"]))
Your word is: p-t--n
```

A hint for the whole program: you will want to use a while loop and have a counter to keep track of how many incorrect guesses are made.